# How to make php flush() working on nginx without access to server conf

Tags: php, nginx, flush

I am searching for solution how to make php `flush()` working on nginx without access to server conf files. 
Because I found some solutions, but they require to mod server conf files. And due hosting rules, I dont have access to them.

Comment: This function appears to be very inconsistent across different platforms. Consider using something like `ob_flush` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right, flush is very inconsistent, I tried `ob_flush` but doesnt work too.